# switch actionbar Style with fragments

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a non swipe-able pager in a main activity with 6 fragments that appears on it, the main activity's Action bar has a specific style and actions, I need to change the style, buttons and the actions for each fragment.

any simple short to the point ideas ?

my project mini API is 11

Comment: How do you want to change the style? What does your current style look like?

Comment: i did added all buttons in the same view and controlled their visibility through java code, i'll post them sunday inchallah, thanks :)